# Google Search Sitemaps

Tags: html, sitemap

Does anyone know of any good tutorials that would show me how to create a sitemap similar to the image below.  I can't figure out how to add the different sections underneath like the Your Account, FAQs, etc.
Any help would be extremely helpful.  Thank you.

google search for instagram

[image]

Comment: You may need to clarify you question. Do you mean an xml site map so that when google crawls your site it will generate something like your example?

Comment: @vector yes this is correct, I am looking for an xml sitemap that will generate the same format as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is what Google calls [Sitelinks](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334).

The process is automated and it's not possible right now to create them but you can manage them with the Google's web master tools. The algorithm used by Google to generate them is [not public](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitelink).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this: http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/), or just google 'xml sitemap generator'
I remember that what happened (in my 'previous' life, when I had to take care of all the gory details of our company site) I just followed google's recommended seo suggestions. It was painstaking and slow, but over time when we started turning up at the top of sear results, that exactly how google presented us. It pulled relevant information on it's own and created that nice display. Looking at my old codebase I don't even see a sitemap file there. But I do remember using one of those online generators and then hand turning it a bit.